# Can't bypass Cloudflare protection using Python Seleniumbase

Tags: python, pytest, cloudflare, webautomation, seleniumbase

I'm developing a software that visits a website, clicking some buttons, closing browser and doing it again in a loop. But the problem is: I am trying to do it for a website that is protected by CloudFlare. Without using any proxy it can bypass most of the time but when im using proxies it can nıt bypass 99%.

```
while True:
    # renew_tor_ip()
    # for x in goodProxy:
    if driversN < driverLimit:
        driversN += 1
        randomList = proxyList[randint(0, len(proxyList)-1)]
        print(randomList)
        if opt == 'y':
            cmd = f'pytest w.py --gui --uc --proxy={randomList} --no-summary -q --multi-proxy --disable-ws'
        elif opt == 'n':
            cmd = f'pytest w.py --gui --uc --no-summary -q --disable-ws'
        Thread(target=access_site, args=(cmd, )).start()
    if driversN >= driverLimit:
        print(f'sleeping', end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

That's the part of the code that I believe that I need to change a bit to fix the issue.

Website is dexscreener.com. I tried to find its direct IP address so i could connect website without CloudFlare but seems like they thought it before so i couldn't find it anywhere. I'm using undetected chromedriver mode of Seleniumbase but it does not help when im using proxies.

Comment: The owner of the website doesn't want your software visiting their site, and they have put Cloudflare bot protection in place to stop you. Why do you think we should help you circumvent that?